# How do I prevent crashing my ec2 micro instance mysql db?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon ec2 micro instance that holds a WordPress site. Since yesterday, my mysql db keep crashing saying:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ sudo service mysqld status
mysqld dead but subsys locked
```

I tried restarting the mysqld but after every 5 mins it keeps crashing with the same message - "Error establishing a database connection"

This is what my DB log file reads -

```
160123 05:44:41 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
160123  5:44:43 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46) starting as process 7928 ...
160123  5:44:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Aborting    
160123  5:44:46 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: Shutdown complete
160123 05:44:46 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

The common solution that found out there when I Googled for a solution for the issue - `mysqld dead but subsys locked`, is to create a swapfile. I did exactly as most of the solution suggest but since I'm not well versed with UNIX, I don't know what I have done is right or not.

As asked by Wounter, updating my question with results of `free`. I have a swap space of 1MB.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx /]$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1019452     613820     405632         76      19124      64348
-/+ buffers/cache:     530348     489104
Swap:      1048572      46604    1001968
```

[image]

Or, Is there any other solution for this issue. Kindly help.

Comment: You need to fix your `mysql` configuration. You have it configured to use more memory than your system has. [mysqltuner](http://mysqltuner.com/) can help you determine the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, the message `mysqld dead but subsys locked` is a *symptom*, not a *cause*. That is, it means mysqld crashed ("dead"), and the init system's state database has outdated information ("but subsys locked"). It doesn't tell you *why* things crashed.

The problem is explained in your mysql server log:

```
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160123  5:44:46 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160123  5:44:46 [ERROR] Aborting
```

This says that when InnoDB (the storage engine) tries to initialize, it wants to allocate 128M of RAM to an `mmap()`'ed region, but that this fails.

You state that you have added swapspace. This should indeed be the correct solution given the error message, but apparently it didn't work; probably because you didn't add enough swap space.

Try increasing the size of your swap space. If that doesn't fix it, please run `free`, and update your question to post the output of that command.